# How to get Android application theme background color dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color

I need to apply theme background color to TextView background color. If describes the process bit  here, this text field is used to choose font color for users. For the moment it is transparent. This is what I tried so far:

```
TypedValue typedValue=new TypedValue();
                    getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowBackground, typedValue, true);
                    if(typedValue.type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT && typedValue.type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT){
                        backgroundColor=typedValue.data;

                        fontColorText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textValue);
                        fontColorText.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
                    }
```

But this is not working for me.

Could anyone suggest me how to get the theme color dynamically?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution. I haven't found one yet...

Comment: @Mgamerz    No, not yet

Comment: @Mgamerz Did you find anything useful to this question?

Comment: Sadly no :( I still need a solution...

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post searching for a solution to the same problem.  Your question helped me develop this answer:

```
    TypedValue themeBackgroundColor = new TypedValue();
    int backgroundColor;

    if (getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorBackground,
            themeBackgroundColor, true)) {
        switch (themeBackgroundColor.type) {
            case TypedValue.TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB4:
                backgroundColor = Color.argb(
                        (themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xf000) >> 8,
                        (themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xf00) >> 4,
                        themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xf0,
                        (themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xf) << 4);
                break;

            case TypedValue.TYPE_INT_COLOR_RGB4:
                backgroundColor = Color.rgb(
                        (themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xf00) >> 4,
                        themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xf0,
                        (themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xf) << 4);
                break;

            case TypedValue.TYPE_INT_COLOR_ARGB8:
                backgroundColor = themeBackgroundColor.data;
                break;

            case TypedValue.TYPE_INT_COLOR_RGB8:
                backgroundColor = Color.rgb(
                        (themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xff0000) >> 16,
                        (themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xff00) >> 8,
                        themeBackgroundColor.data & 0xff);
                break;

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("ClassName: couldn't parse theme " +
                        "background color attribute " + themeBackgroundColor.toString());
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("ClassName: couldn't find background color in " +
                "theme");
    }
```

I verified that `colorBackground` is a specified attribute in Material, Holo, and pre-Holo themes.  Also, since there doesn't seem to be a guarantee that the theme's background is specified in AARRGGBB format, I put in the switch statement to deal with all the valid formats.  I've checked this for all cases of color.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        Spannable s1 = new SpannableString("These is the Way we can change the background textView");        

        s1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 1, 25, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        t1.setText(s1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't need the add a theme. What I need is to change the text field back ground color according to current theme background color. BTW thanks for the support.

Comment: u need to change the textView Background color?

Comment: Yes, I need to change the textfield background color to same as the color in application background.

Comment: check the answer.It will be helpfull to you

Comment: Here you hard coded the text field background color as "ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE)".But what I need is as I described in my question, change the color same as the theme color always in background even when the theme changed while application running.